# Function that returns View can't compile

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to return View depending on case.

```
@ViewBuilder
private func getView(case: Case) -> some View {
    switch case {
    case .case1:
        View1()
    case .case2:
        View2()
    case .case3:
        View3()
    }
}
```

I use it like this:

```
NavigationLink(destination: getView(case: case)) { ...
```

But this code can't compile, I get error

> "The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable
> time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"

I get this error even if I try to return just one View, like this:

```
@ViewBuilder
private func getView(case: Case) -> some View {
    View1()
}
```

But if I use View directly in NavigationLink then everything works normally:

```
NavigationLink(destination: View1()) { ...
```

Why is this happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: What is `View1`? What is you try with `Text("Hello, world!")` instead of `View1`?

Comment: Shouldn't the `getView` function return the view: e.g `return View1()`?

Comment: @Fogmeister `View1` is new screen, it is pretty complex, it has ScrollView, VStack, ForEach, HStack, etc. I tried with  `Text("Hello, world!")` instead of `View1`, but I get the same result.

Comment: @tromgy If you use `@ViewBuilder` you shouldn't use return. If you use return `@ViewBuilder` will be ignored.

Comment: @Mdev yeah, even if you needed the return on the single line function it's implicit anyway. So wouldn't solve the issue.

Comment: The code in your question does not compile, because `case` is not a valid name for a variable. Amending it to use a valid name, I do not see any compilation error or reasonable time warning in Xcode 14.2, so there's likely something in your actual code that you are not showing us that is causing the problem. Please update the question with real code.

Answer (score 2):

If you really *must* call your variable `case`, or some other reserved word, enclose it in backticks, e.g.

```
@ViewBuilder
    private func getView(case: Case) -> some View {
        switch `case` {
        case .case1:
            View1()
        case .case2:
            View2()
        case .case3:
            View3()
        }
    }
```